# Error find: paths must precede expression with Linux command

Tags: linux, unix

I am getting below error:

> "find: paths must precede expression: zip"

I am trying to execute below:

```
cd /ohi/oraBase/Extract_Files; BACKUPFILE=OIG_EXTRACT_FILES-$(date); ERR_LOG_FILE=`echo "ODI_Readable_File.log" | cut -f 1 -d '.'`; mkdir "$BACKUPFILE"; find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "ERR_LOG_FILE".* -exec mv {} "/ohi/oraBase/Extract_Files/$BACKUPFILE" \; zip -r "$BACKUPFILE".zip "$BACKUPFILE";
```

Below is working fine:

```
cd /ohi/oraBase/Extract_Files; BACKUPFILE=OIG_EXTRACT_FILES-$(date); ERR_LOG_FILE=`echo "ODI_Readable_File.log" | cut -f 1 -d '.'`; mkdir "$BACKUPFILE"; find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "ERR_LOG_FILE".* -exec mv {} "/ohi/oraBase/Extract_Files/$BACKUPFILE" \;
```

Looks like below is culprit:

```
zip -r "$BACKUPFILE".zip "$BACKUPFILE";
```

If I execute each command one time, even zip is working.

why error in single line execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. I needed second ; after zip command zip -r "$BACKUPFILE".zip "$BACKUPFILE";
some how it was not seprating zip command with find.